# Change the way i load resources

Tags: c++, sfml

I have made a few games using c++ sfml and they work pretty well. I think my game structuring needs alot of work. At the moment I load all my sprites and textures at the begining of my main function, and then pass them wherever needed. 
could someone give me any advice on where i should declare these, or is it acceptable. if you have any links that would help me learn a better way that would be nice. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is to have a ResourceManager class, which contains a hash table mapping resource names (or paths, if you prefer) to the actual resource instances (sf::Sound, sf::Texture).

When a user requests a certain resource (e.g., by calling `ResourceManager::getTexture("res/texture.png")`), the ResourceManager class checks if a texture with name `"res/texture.png"` has already been loaded. If so, it returns a reference to the sf::Texture object associated with that string. Otherwise, it creates a new sf::Texture, stores it in the hash table for further use, and returns a reference to it.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697598/using-c-templating-for-sfml-resource-manager) question for more inspiration.